# Ubuntu 14.04: What happen there is a user with UID = 0 but it is not root?

Tags: uid

If I create a non-root user and I change it UID = 0. The system also have root user. Does it mean that the system is going to give root permission to this user? If not, are there any security problems by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

`UID==0` is the definition for the all-powerful `root` user. If you create a userid with `UID==0` it will be the `root` user, no matter what you call it. They are many, many security problems associated with multiple `root` accounts. Tracability, for one.

Comment: What if I create two users with UID=0? Are they both root automatically?